# Best User Login implementation iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a web developer that has recently moved over to iOS dev. I have implemented a login system for my website and I want to integrate this same functionality within my app. I will have login UI in the app that communicates with the web server using the AFNetworking library to make POST requests.

However, I am not sure how I will deal with remembering things in regard to user logins such as whether the user was logged in previously? With Web, I would do cookies and sessions, but I am not sure whether this is the best approach with iOS. I've also read about some people talking about storing things within the iOS keychain for security reasons. Can anyone shine some light on what the best practise for achieving what I want would be?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not positive, but I'm pretty sure AFNetworking stores cookies automatically.  Any other information sounds like it would be a good use for `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`

Comment: The iOS keychain is better for storing passwords and other encrypted information. Filip's answer and Logans comment are the way you should go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use NSUserDefaults but I think you should use token-based approach for your iOS client. When ever you log in and get a successful response, you should store your token in user defaults with the following code.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:token forKey:@"auth_token"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Your logout function could look something like this.

```
- (void)logout {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:nil forKey:@"auth_token"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

You can send this auth_token each time you make a web request so that the server knows those requests are authorized.

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering if you can elaborate more on this "token" you are talking about?

Comment: You can see this link http://blog.auth0.com/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/ for the difference between traditional cookie-based approach and newer token-based approach.

Answer (score 1):

In objective-C there is the [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that can be used similarly.

To save a bool value for example you would do the following

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"IsLoggedIn"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

to later load the value you write

```
BOOL isLoggedIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"IsLoggedIn"];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Just to add on, I'd suggest creating a `.h` file to store all your keys, so you don't have to keep looking through your code or write them down somewhere. Then just import it whenever you use `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: Milo has a great point! This will significantly reduce the chance of typing errors and improve readability at the same time.